# How to make no reset list position of listview with sliver appbar in normal scroll by another tab

Tags: flutter

I have simple Flutter app with sliver appbar and tabbar with each tab have listview I want to create preserve scroll position and that working great with this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/ListOne.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/ListTwo.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
    late TabController _controller;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();

        _controller = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            // appBar: AppBar(
            //  title: Text('Testing'),
            //  bottom: TabBar(
            //      controller: _controller,
            //      tabs: [
            //          Tab(text: 'ONE'),
            //          Tab(text: 'TWO'),
            //      ],
            //  ),
            // ),
            body: NestedScrollView(
                floatHeaderSlivers: true,
                headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
                    SliverAppBar(
                        floating: true,
                        pinned: true,
                        bottom: TabBar(
                            controller: _controller,
                            tabs: [
                                Tab(text: 'ONE'),
                                Tab(text: 'TWO'),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
                body: TabBarView(
                    controller: _controller,
                    children: [
                        buildPageOne(),
                        buildPageTwo(),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    Widget buildPageOne() => ListView.builder(
        key: const PageStorageKey<String>('pagOne'),
        itemCount: 50,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
            title: Text('PAGE $index'),
        ),
    );

    Widget buildPageTwo() => ListView.builder(
        key: const PageStorageKey<String>('pageTwo'),
        itemCount: 50,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
            title: Text('PAGE2 $index'),
        ),
    );
}
```

First I scrolling from tab 1 until list of number 30

I have switched to tab 2 and do scrolling down until the end of list that make sliver appbar to normal

and I navigate to tab 1 again and I have a problem, the problem is scroll position of tab 1 which is before is to 30 position that reset to zero position.

so how to make tab 1 not rested if SliverAppbar in normal